# Unexpected class name 'btn-primary' is added automatically in bootstrap drupal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I build a drupal website and use bootstrap to theme.
I override search button by using **MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)** to add bootstrap class "**btn-default**" with this line in function:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'] = array('btn-default');
```

and if I assign any value to **$form['actions']['submit']['#value']** but not the word "search" as below:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = "blah blah";//"blah blah" or anything else but not "search"
```

Then the output is rendered as I expected. My button is belong to **btn-default** class with white-grey color.

**But if I assign like these two below:**

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = "search";
```

or

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>"; //this line is to change the button to icon button
```

Then the class name "**btn-primary**" will be automatically added to the classes of button element, like this:

```
<button class="btn-default btn btn-primary">
```

Now my button is blue color button because of **btn-primary** class.

I think some javascript of bootstrap did something automatically, and I don't know how to solve this problem.
Can anybody help me? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is that the actual rendered output or what you see in your browser dev tools?

Comment: Yes, it is. Ex: If the #value is "saerch" then rendered output is:
`<button class="btn-default btn form-submit" id="edit-submit--4" name="op" value="saerch" type="submit" data-thmr="thmr_46">saerch</button>`


and if the #value is exactly "search" then it will as below:


`<button class="btn-default btn btn-primary form-submit" id="edit-submit--4" name="op" value="search" type="submit" data-thmr="thmr_46">search</button>`

Comment: This is a 'feature' of that particular theme - you can turn it off by disabling "Colorize Buttons" in the theme settings

Comment: Hi @Clive, you save my time, but I don't know how to override the function in **bootstrap/theme/common.inc**.
I found the function **_bootstrap_colorize_button($text)** which automatically check and add the **btn-primary** to button element's class.
I tried to override by creating a function named **mysubtheme_bootstrap_colorize_button($text)** in **mysubtheme/template.php** and add some conditions to only ignore the case of "search" button, but it doesn't work.
I did some search but don't find document about overriding functions in **bootstrap/theme/common.inc file**.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I solved it.
I override the function **bootstrap_preprocess_button** instead.
Add **settings[colorize_search_button_enabled] = 1** to **mytheme.info** and use **theme_get_setting** to quick toggle the functionality.
Thanks again.